# aireplay-ng --deauth never finds BSSID available

Tags: wifi, wpa2, aircrack-ng, handshake

I've been trying to crack wifi wpa2 handshake using airodump-ng and aireplay-ng.

I'm using alfa awus-036acs adapter.

```
sudo airodump-ng wlan0
sudo airodump-ng --bssid  MAC ADDR of AP --channel 1 -w capture  wlan0
```

and (tried both)

```
sudo aireplay-ng --deauth 0 -a MAC ADDR OF AP  wlan0
```

or

```
sudo aireplay-ng --deauth 1111 -a MAC ADDR OF AP -c MAC ADDR OF CLIENT wlan0
```

and every time it shows

```
Waiting for beacon frame (BSSID: MAC ADDR) on channel 1 no such BSSID available.
```

The pwr is 80 so shouldn't be a problem.
I've tried this on many networks, but always the output is the same as above.

I am using kali in VMware fusion on Mac.

Also tried:

```
airmon-ng check kill
```

and

```
ifconfig wlan0 down
```

before running aireplay-ng

What is causing this to show that there is no BSSID available?
When I type `-D` it throws:

```
17:14:52  Sending 64 directed DeAuth (code 7). STMAC: 
[MAC ADDR] [ 0|61 ACKs]
 
17:14:52  Sending 64 directed DeAuth (code 7). STMAC:
[MAC ADDR] [ 0|60 ACKs]
 
17:14:53  Sending 64 directed DeAuth (code 7). STMAC:
[MAC ADDR] [ 0|64 ACKs]
```

Comment: and you checked that your card is in monitor mode?

Comment: yeah, it is in monitor mode